# How to compare 'OBJECT' stored as a BLOB inside the sqlite database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a database which contains an OBJECT column. Can I compare the object stored inside that column with another object.? Can I read the individual datafields inside the object?

I have the following code which creates the table.

```
var sqlQuery:String = "create table test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
+ "options OBJECT)";
var sqlStatement:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
sqlStatement.text = sqlQuery;
sqlStatement.execute();
```

To input the data, I do

```
var sqlQuery:String = "insert into test(options) values(@obj)";
var sqlStatement:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
sqlStatement.text = sqlQuery;
sqlStatement.parameters["@obj"] = myObject;
sqlStatement.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite [has no OBJECT data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).
You can *name* the column type whatever you want, but as for the actual values, the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd47bd22bdd97276f2aceae3b1262b7f2d43-8000.html) says:

> Object column data is serialized in AMF3 format and stored using the BLOB storage class.

Such values can be compared with others, but this compares the entire value.

There are no built-in functions to extract fields from text or blob values, except for [substr()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr).

Comment: Its there in the Adobe Flex, I can create the table with OBJECT column, I can store an Object into it.

Comment: As I said, you can *name* the column type whatever you want, but as far as SQLite is concerned, OBJECT has exactly the same meaning as FLUFFY BUNNIES.

Comment: Okay, lets say its stored as BLOB. How do I compare BLOB texts?

Comment: Blob comparisons work like with any other type (`... WHERE options = @obj ...`), but this works only if both objects are completely identical and have the same serialization.

Comment: Okay, I'll try with comparing Blobs